# Big text in Android

Tags: android, text, antialiasing

I am trying to resize text in android to make it bigger using;

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(30);
canvas.drawText("Text goes here" , x, y,paint);
```

However the text gets pixelated.

Is there any other way of resizing text in android without it being ugly and pixelated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried `Paint.setAntiAlias(true)` to turn on [anti-aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing)? `Paint.setSubpixelText(true)` might also help.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html

Comment: That worked, thank you very much! (Can't upvote you since I don't have enough reputation).

Comment: I don't think you need any reputation to 'accept' (clicking the tick) an answer though :)