# How to make Android drawText fonts better looking?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write text on a canvas using drawText. And i use font size 20 here.

[image]

But the text appears to be not very nice. Does any one knows how to change the font in to a better one. If there are ways other than using drawText please give me some examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big text in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690628/big-text-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting antiAlias on your paint.

```
textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
```